# How to search suggestion with my own search engine in the google chrome's input field

Tags: javascript, php, ajax

I made a search engine on my web site. At now if I go to the search page all work correctly. I wanted to search directly by the search box in chrome. So I went in the setting and set the search engine. The problem is that chrome doesn't show suggestions for my search engine. But I don't know how to give to chrome the strings of the suggestions.

Comment: You might want to accept the answer to this question, if it helped you.

Answer (score 1):

You are looking for ["OpenSearch"](http://www.opensearch.org/Home).  Specifically, you need to:

- Provide a link to an open search [description document](https://github.com/dewitt/opensearch/blob/master/opensearch-1-1-draft-6.md#opensearch-description-document) [in your HTML](https://github.com/dewitt/opensearch/blob/master/opensearch-1-1-draft-6.md#autodiscovery-in-htmlxhtml) or in a `Link` HTTP header:

  ```
  <link rel="search"
    type="application/opensearchdescription+xml"
    href="http://example.com/content-search.xml"
    title="Content search" />
  ```
- Include a `Url` element of `rel=suggestions`, e. g.:

  ```
  <Url type="application/json"
     rel="suggestions"
     template="http://example.com/suggest?q={searchTerms}" />
  ```
- Respond to requests to that URL with a list of suggestions in the nested array format [described in the specification](http://www.opensearch.org/Specifications/OpenSearch/Extensions/Suggestions/1.1#JSON-formatted_search_suggestion_responses):

  ```
  ["sea",                # User's search term
    ["sears",            # Suggested search terms
     "search engines",
     "search engine",
     "search",
     "sears.com",
     "seattle times"],
    ["7,390,000 results",    # Suggested search descriptions
     "17,900,000 results",
     "25,700,000 results",
     "1,220,000,000 results",
     "1 result",
     "17,600,000 results"],
    ["http://example.com?q=sears",  # Links for suggested searches (optional)
     "http://example.com?q=search+engines",
     "http://example.com?q=search+engine",
     "http://example.com?q=search",
     "http://example.com?q=sears.com",
     "http://example.com?q=seattle+times"]]
  ```

See also: https://github.com/dewitt/opensearch